# Finding the review results for a specific question

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

When I vote to close or reopen a question through the review queue, I can always go back to see the review results of that question, i.e. who else reviewed that question and how they decided

However I cannot find a way to see this for questions when I vote for reopening or closing through the question itself.

Is there a way to get this result?

I admit do not have a much practical use for this sort of information, besides idle curiosity. Still, it would be nice to see why a nomination failed or succeeded review, or whether the decision was unanimous

Specifically, I edited and nominated [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242320/ignore-a-property-during-xml-serialization-but-not-during-deserialization) for reopening earlier today.
I could not see this question in the reopen queue, I presume because I already voted on it.
The question has now been reopened, but I can find no way to see how the review went.

Comment: [Here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/4235467). One method is to find it from the [reopen review history](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/history) manually. And the history shows all reviews only if you have 10k otherwise only your review history will be visible.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the "artisanal" method I followed:

1. From the question history, find the users who voted to reopen,
2. Choose a user, go to their profile, find in their activity history the review pertaining to that question,
3. Follow the link to that review.

In your case, it's [there](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/4235467).

Comment: This is better as even non 10k users also see this.

Comment: This works well, though I think only if the review is already finished and has caused the state of the question to change. So no reviews currently in progress, or reviews that caused the question to remain open/closed)

Comment: @Hugo, true, that's a limited solution, especially in the last case you specify.